# Internet Explorer 8 Jquery drop down Issue

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

I am using jquery drop down menu on my website. The website works perfectly on all browsers except IE8 on which I get errors and hence the drop down menu can't load. I am not too sure about other versions of IE whether they have same problem or not.

Here are error messages that I get on IE:
Webpage error details

```
Message: 'Config' is undefined
Line: 1
Char: 48671
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/Yariga/New/js/all-min.js


Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object
Line: 5557
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/Yariga/New/js/prototype.js


Message: Permission denied
Line: 35269113
Char: 23
Code: 0
URI: http://cdn.io4o.com/ga.html
```

Here is URL:
http://stats.yariga.net

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks
Ahmar.

Comment: prototype.js : Are you mixing JQuery and prototype libs? It could be a problem.

Comment: Hi but errors don't show conflict rather they are about undefined etc

Answer (score 0):

Put your `<!-- DOCTYPE html -->` Before Html tag
Right now your doctype is in body.

Comment: 0.o are you sure? it is outside html tag. Just checked it now?

Comment: did that and still same problem. ?